# Change Desktop Background in Windows 8.1 using Python 3.4 in Real TIme

Tags: python, windows, background, desktop

This has been solved by [erykson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun):

```
import os, ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1
SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 2
image_path = os.path.abspath("image.jpg")
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, image_path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

Here's a single line version

```
import os, ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, os.path.abspath("image.jpg"), 1 | 2)
```

> I would like to begin by stating that using the ctypes method has been
>   unsuccessful for me and calling a powershell function has also been
>   unsuccessful for me.
>
> The goal of my program is to change the desktop background in real
>   time when the program runs.  I've been unsuccessful in my attempts and
>   I am relatively new to doing such a task.  If anyone can guide me with
>   a nice bit of code and a little explanation on how it works, that
>   would be most appreciated.  Again, this is for Windows 8.1 64bit and I
>   am using Python 3.4.3 64bit.  I have jpg files, but I can use any
>   format as long as it works.  Thank you for any possible solutions or
>   for a semi-detailed description on why this won't work.
>
> PowerShell Function Code
>
> ```
> Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
> {
>  Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
>  rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
> }
> ```
>
> PowerShell Call Code in Python
>
> ```
> import subprocess
> subprocess.Popen([r'path/to/PowerShell/script.exe',
>                      '-ExecutionPolicy',
>                      'Unrestricted',
>                      'path/to/background_image.png'], cwd=os.getcwd())
> ```
>
> and then I've tried this with ctypes, shows a black screen
>
> ```
> import ctypes
> SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
> ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
> ```
>
> Before anyone asks, yes I changed the directories when implementing
>   these lines.

Comment: Please show us the code you have attempted?

Comment: Python 3 uses Unicode strings, so call `SystemParametersInfoW`. You should also update the registry and broadcast the change by passing `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE` in `fWinIni` (4th argument).

Comment: I have less than 6 months experience with coding, so I'm not really picking up what you put down.

Comment: `import os, ctypes;` `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;` `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1;` `SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 2;` `image_path = os.path.abspath("image.jpg");` `success = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, image_path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)`